# How to "find and replace" strings in a file from SPIFFS on ESP8266/ESP32?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp32

I am running a little web server on the ESP-32 and having the HTML files on the flash memory accessing it by SPIFFS. I have some status fields which I would like to insert dynamically into the static HTML files. Therefore I defined some custom placeholders like `{data_recv}` and `{data_sent}` which should be replaced by field values from the code and then being served by the web server to the client browser.

When a client browser requests one of the HTML pages, I am going to read them with SPIFFS like:

```
  if(SPIFFS.exists(path)) {                             // if the file exists
    File file = SPIFFS.open(path, "r");                 // open it

    // TODO: replace placeholders {data_recv} and {data_sent} with field values ...

    size_t sent = server.streamFile(file, contentType); // and send it to the client
    file.close();                                       // then close the file again
    return true;
  }
```

Some ideas how to implement a "find-and-replace" function for the `File` type?

Something with the following function signature:

```
bool findAndReplace(File file, String searchStr, String replaceStr) {
    // implementation ...
}
```

Comment: It would be relatively easy to read the file into memory and then perform a find and replace however this suffers from a huge problem.  The problem is that we are likely memory constrained and can't read the whole file into RAM to perform the search.  Instead, what we are likely going to want to do is read in the data a byte at a time and look for the patterns in a stream based approach.  As we read data, if it doesn't match a pattern, we would pass it straight through.  However if it prefixes a pattern, we would hold off sending it until we can either replace the pattern or pass it through.

Comment: if you get it into a string, there's a string.replace command that makes it easy.

Comment: @dandavis Yes I did that. But I need to include `bootstrap.css` and `jquery.js` to my web page hosted on the ESP32. These two files are soo large that they don't fit into a String in Arduino IDE.

Comment: do you need to modify either of those files? i would think they can be served as-is, while a smaller custom file gets templated.

Comment: @dandavis No I don't have to modify these two files. My web interface consists of two small HTML file which make use of `bootstrap.css` and `jquery.js`. So you think of using the HTML files as `String`s, replacing my placeholders with `String.replace` and serve the larger  `bootstrap.css` and `jquery.js` from SPIFFS? How would I have to implement this? Currently I am serving the HTML with `server.send(200, "text/html", page);` whereas I earlier did serve the `bootstrap.css` and `jquery.js` with `server.streamFile(file, contentType);`. How to combine these two approaches?

Comment: I think I understand how to implement it. I add `<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">` and `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` to the HTML header and the client browser will then automatically request these two files which in turn can be served by the ESP32 using `server.streamFile(file, contentType);`.

Comment: yes, use `server.on` for the templating, and the 404-based (onNotFound) file-handler for the un-modified ones. there's also a way to do chunked responses, so that you can serve big files templated; reading a few kb of file, turning to a string, replacing, sending, repeating. The one complication with that is making sure you don't split the chunks on a template placeholder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be **not** to rewrite the files but to replace the values while answering the requests.

Instead of using `server.streamFile(file, contentType)` you would use a buffer to read the file block-wise using `fread(buffer, 1, len, file)`, replace the pattern in the buffer (the tricky part is that you have to keep track of partial matches at the end of the buffer) and send the buffer to the client.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @dandavid said on comments, you don't need to analyse `bootstrap.css` or other static files.
2. You can have an static HTML and get the placeholders updated by using JavaScript: doing `XMLHttpRequest` queries. So you only have to implement a path that returns a JSON with the values of each placeholder.